# Modifying a closed excel sheet with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to open one spredsheet from another so that it isn't in view. I would then like to change the column format of one of the columns to date using the TextToColumns feature. The changes should then be saved and the file closed automatically.

When I run the following it says No data was selected to parse. Any thoughts?

```
Sub Test()

Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet

xlApp.Visible = False

Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("directory of file")

Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
xlWS.Unprotect


    xlWS.Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


Set xlWS = Nothing
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlWB.Close True
Set xlWB = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by closed? Do you mean the Workbook the sheet is in is closed? Or do you mean that another sheet has the focus?

Comment: There are two worbooks. One is open. The other is not. I would like the open one to open the second in the background, change the data types of some columns. Save the changes and then close the hidden workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of research should have given you the result, but I will provide it anyway...

```
'Since you want the Workbook to be invisible, we have to open it in a new Excel Application
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet

xlApp.Visible = False

'Open Workbook from specified path
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("YOUR FILEPATH HERE")

'Select Worksheet from opened Workbook
Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("YOUR WORKSHEET NAME HERE")

'Do something
'example
xlWS.Name = "Asdf"

'Cleanup
Set xlWS = Nothing
xlWB.Close 'True to save changes, False to discard changes
Set xlWB = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. To save to changes what do you change to True?

Comment: `xlWB.Close True` instead of `xlWB.Close`

Comment: When you do that it brings up the save as window though. I have tried using xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False. Do you know how to just save over the current file without being prompted?

Comment: setting `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False` before the `xlWB.Close` should work fine. If it doesn't do the trick, you can try to set `.DisplayAlerts = False` for Application, too (`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started...

```
Sub Test()

  Dim wbk As Workbook

  'Open the workbook that is closed
  Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\OtherWorkbook.xlsx")

  'Change the format of the first column
  wbk.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "0.00"

  'Close the workbook and save changes
  wbk.Close True


End Sub
```